# How to copy paste audio track from/to mp4

Tags: audio, video, extract, copy-paste, decompiling

i have 2 video streams,

DVD is a big (4.6 GB) iso file white a dutch audio track (it's my own dvd)
Mp4 is a small (800MB) mp4 file white a eng audio track.

I search for a tool that van pick the audio track from the DVD and place it in the mp4, how can i do this?

jens.

Comment: What will the -2 say?

Comment: Did you try to Google for **[Iso file opener](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=nqYkUqj1Osi20QXAhoHoDQ#q=iso+file+opener)**? Use a video editing tool like **[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm)** to remux the audio and video together. I'm assuming you got down-voted for not saying what you tried and also you dont even say tool for what, Windows or Mac? If you expect them to guess how to help you they will hate you for it. I understand you are new to the site so I could only cancel one down-vote.. PS: `decompiling` is not relevant tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handbrake did the job, everything works find now.